# Find keyword name (or keyword name stack) in Robot Framework

Tags: python, testing, robotframework, keyword

I've been struggling with the same problem as in this question: [Robot Framework location and name of keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538356/robot-framework-location-and-name-of-keyword) - i need to find a keyword name stack (I'm not interested in keyword file name for now).
Seems like the author has found the solution.
Unfortunately, I cannot apply it because in my version of Robot Framework (3.0.2) object _ExecutionContext has no field or property keywords, so in my case the line  `EXECUTION_CONTEXTS.current.keywords[-1].name`
raises an exception. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you _just_ need a keyword name stack, or do you need the filename associated with the keyword as asked for in the question you linked to?

Comment: How are you planning on using this information? Does it need to be accessible by other keywords? Are you saving it to a file or database?

Comment: I know that it is contrary with good practices of testing, but I need to know if certain keywords were executed before current and execute them if they were not. I'm trying to make test cases depend on others. I know it is not a good practice, but I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is probably to combine a [keyword library and listener into a single module](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-libraries-as-listeners). The listener can keep track of the keywords that have been called, and the library can provide keywords that give access to that list of keywords.

Here's a really basic example. There's no error checking, and it requires an exact match, but it illustrates the general idea.

First, the custom library:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class CustomLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.keywords = []

    # this defines a keyword named "Require Keyword"
    def require_keyword(self, kwname):
        if kwname not in self.keywords:
            raise Exception("keyword '%s' hasn't been run" % kwname)

    # this defines the "start keyword" listener method.
    # the leading underscore prevents it from being treated
    # as a keyword
    def _start_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        self.keywords.append(name)
```

Next, an example of its use:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  CustomLibrary.py

*** Keywords ***
Example keyword
    pass

*** Test Cases ***
Example test case
    log    hello, world!

    # this will pass, since we called the log keyword
    require keyword    BuiltIn.Log

    # this will fail because we haven't called the example keyword
    require keyword    Example keyword
```

Comment: I modified this solution slightly, so it better fits my needs, but I would get nowhere without your help. Thank you very much! :)